# Fill an XML file with test data

Tags: java, xml, git

I have an XML file looks like the attached image: [image: XML file]

The attributes (commitId, author, date, and time) in  I got it from Git open source repository using "blame" command.

However, for my evaluation, I need to fill these attributes randomly with data I have. For example, I have Junio, Peter, Jiang, Jens, Jeff, Ramkumar, and Linus as authors, and date is ranged between 2010 and 2012.

what is the best way to fill this data using Java?

Comment: Is this a question about how to generate the random data, or how to put that data into XML?

Comment: It's how to generate it.

Comment: If this is for testing, consider using TestNG and a `@DataProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by placing the values you need into arrays like this:

```
   String names[] = {Junio, Peter, Jiang, Jens, Jeff, Ramkumar, Linus};
   String dates[] = {2010, 2011, 2012};
```

Then using the Random class you can do this:

```
    Random ran = new Random();
    String name = names[ran.nextInt(7)];
    String date = dates[ran.nextInt(3)];
```

That will give you a random name and date. Rinse. Repeat.

Note that to get a random number between 0 and n inclusive you need nextInt(n + 1).

Comment: but Random add different authors in each fragment. But, if you see in the attachment, sometimes the fragment has one name